# SSH Port Forward Error

Tags: raspbian, networking, ssh, server, putty

I can't get the SSH to work on my Raspbian Raspberry Pi (it is enabled). I am port forwarding the pi's external IP to port 22 but putty says the connection has been refused. I'm a beginner as far as networking goes so please excuse any silly mistakes if there are any.

I am also new to stack exchange as well so if I need to provide more information please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Please provide us with more information. How are you forwarding? iptables or something like it? Please explain the paths from client to server, listing the forwarders.

Comment: I'm actually forwarding using my verizon router. I haven't changed anything on the pi.

Comment: Are you trying to ssh to the Pi from a computer that is connected to the same router as the Pi ?

Comment: I am but I want to be able to connect from anywhere, which is why I'm forwarding the external IP. I can connect while on my wifi.

Comment: Port forwarding usually only works on packets coming into the the router from the internet, not on local packets. Try it from the neighbors internet connection, or use a [online ssh client](http://www.serfish.com/console/) (be sure to change the password afterwards, as you shouldn't trust these 3rd parties with you ssh-credentials).

Comment: My connection timed out, does that mean I have a separate issue?

Comment: This means this testing site just could not reach your pi.

Comment: so, you are forwarding port 22 to port 22 pointing to the IP address of RPi, and RPi is with static IP, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

see if this port is open.....mostly your ssh demon is not running. see if sshd is running. If not then start it.

Do you have sshd installed?You can verify that using :

```
  which ssh
  which sshd
```

Make sure that /etc/hosts.allow contains:

```
  ssh:ALL:allow
  sshd:ALL:allow
```

OR

```
  ssh:localhost:allow
  sshd:localhost:allow
```

OR - some other variant

```
  ssh:{host1,host2,host3...}:allow
  sshd{host1,host2,host3...}:allow
```

INSURE that the first line in the file DOES NOT begin with ALL:ALL:DENY

NOTHING will be able to communicate with the host... on any port.

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335728/connect-to-host-localhost-port-22-connection-refused) has links to other related pages